# How to make url address like I want?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I can't find information how to make url address like

> www.example.com/categories/id-category_name

Could you give me example?
Thank you

Comment: check https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine